# Div not performing slideToggle() when clicking on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I want to set up a portfolio where when I click on the picture of "3DBanners", the div with ID "FirstBanners" opens up.

Essentially, go from this: http://prntscr.com/aufua6 to  this: http://prntscr.com/aufups by a slide down and up, hence slideToggle().

Here is my code:

```css
#Thumbnails {
 position:absolute;
 top:460px;
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.70));
    filter:         drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.70));
}
.Thumbs {
 cursor:pointer;
}
.BannerCaptions {
 font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
 text-transform:capitalize;
 font-size:26px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 padding:5px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.StillBanners {
 width:1500px;
}
#DayZSnowy {
 padding-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
<div id="Thumbnails" style="display:none;">
<a id="FirstBannersThumb"><img src="../Images/Thumbnails/3DBanners.png" alt="3D Banners" class="Thumbs" /></a>
<div id="FirstBanners">
 <img src="../Images/Still Benners/DayZSnowy.png" alt="DayZ Snowy" id="DayZSnowy" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="DayZSnowyCaption" class="BannerCaptions">DayZ Snowy Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/InFa.png" alt="InFa Space" id="InFaSpace" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="InFaSpaceCaption" class="BannerCaptions">InFa Space Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/L7Zeon.png" alt="L7 Zeon" id="L7Zeon" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="L7ZeonCaption" class="BannerCaptions">L7 Zeon Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/Mythh.jpg" alt="Void Mythh" id="Mythh" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="MythhCaption" class="BannerCaptions">Void Mythh Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/L7ArtsRiver.png" alt="L7 Arts" id="L7ArtsRiver" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="L7ArtsRiverCaption" class="BannerCaptions">L7 Arts Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/Insan3Lik3Var2.jpg" alt="Insan3Lik3" id="Insan3Lik3" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="Insan3Lik3Caption" class="BannerCaptions">Insan3Lik3 Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/Soulja.JPG" alt="S3 Soulja" id="Soulja" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="SouljaCaption" class="BannerCaptions">S3 Soulja Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/Zorich.jpg" alt="Zorich" id="Zorich" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="ZorichCaption" class="BannerCaptions">Zorich Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/Invade.png" alt="L7 Invade" id="Invade" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="InvadeCaption" class="BannerCaptions">L7 Invade Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/ExampleFX.jpg" alt="ExampleFX" id="ExampleFX" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="ExampleFXCaption" class="BannerCaptions">ExampleFX Banner (This is 3D because some buildings in background are 3D Modelled)</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/Whiz.jpg" alt="SoaR Whiz" id="Whiz" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="WhizCaption" class="BannerCaptions">SoaR Whiz Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/Compleqz.jpg" alt="Compleqz" id="Compleqz" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="CompleqzCaption" class="BannerCaptions">Compleqz Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/Troopa.JPG" alt="Troopa" id="Troopa" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="TroopaCaption" class="BannerCaptions">Troopa Banner</p>
    <img src="../Images/Still Benners/Mega3.jpg" alt="Mega" id="Mega" class="StillBanners" />
    <p id="MegaCaption" class="BannerCaptions">Mega Banner</p>
</div>
<a class="Thumbs"><img src="../Images/Thumbnails/2DBanners.png" alt="2D Banners" id="2DBannersThumb" /></a>
<a class="Thumbs"><img src="../Images/Thumbnails/GIFBanners.png" alt="GIF Banners" id="GIFBannersThumb" /></a>
</div>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#FirstBannersThumb").click(function() {
        $("#FirstBanners").slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gq6vpo5r/1/ - looks just fine, is there any error in the console

Comment: Thanks for the response but there are no errors anywhere in this specific code.  There is various places Dreamweaver says to include "Use Strict" statements but everyone says this isn't really a big issue or problem AND those errors are in other linked files.

Comment: It seems to work great in the fiddle but not in mine for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!  I simply had to remove the document.ready part because it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your jQuery version. 
Replace this

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

for this

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`